# Impact of Spotlight search information removal on Keynote presentation

Tags: macos, keynote

OS X Spotlight search information was removed.
What does this mean for my Keynote presentation made in iWork '09?

Comment: I've attempted to edit the title to clarify the question based on the body, but feel free to edit further.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. The file's contents won't be modified by the deletion of the Spotlight index. It's still in the location that you saved it to.